# Can move mouse but can't click with pyAutoGui

Tags: python, macos-mojave, pyautogui

The `pyautogui` function `click` should move the mouse and click. It moves the mouse but doesn't click.

I'm running the script from iTerm2.

System: MacOS mojave 10.14.4
Python: 3.8.1
iTerm2: 3.3.5

I've seen this come up elsewhere; the suggested solutions (under security and privacy, add python, iterm2, python launcer, IDLE to apps that can control computer) don't work.

```
import pyautogui

click_terminal = (1596, 132)

pyautogui.click(click_terminal[0], click_terminal[1], clicks = 2, duration = 1, button = 'left')
```

Edit: I can right click (with `button = 'right'`) but I can't left click.

Comment: It works for me on Win 10. Try to click on other coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(1372, 670)    # move mouse to the window
pyautogui.dragTo(1372, 670, button = 'left')    # focus the window
pyautogui.click(1372, 670, button = 'left')     # simulate left click
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was wayland. After switching to X, it worked. In /etc/gdm3/custom.conf uncomment the line #WaylandEnable=false.